# How to pass an argument into Views for Drupal 7?

Tags: nodes, views

I'm trying to pass an argument through a block created by a view.

The node is an ubercart product node. I have aliased the paths such as:

node/45 to products/[name]

In contextual filters, I've chosen the filter "Content: Nid"

In the Preview with contextual filters it works with the node id as it should. e.g. "45" but the view doesn't show on the page node/45.

I believe the alias may have caused the problem, but I thought Drupal was designed to have aliases converted to node id's.

Comment: Alias does not effect argument values.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31576/how-do-you-pass-page-arguments-from-panels-to-a-view/86655

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your contextual filter, under **WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS *NOT* AVAILABLE**, choose **Provide default value** and select "Content ID from URL" under **Type**.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I figured out you need to do this for blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define an "Exception value" in the "Provide default value" option, like "all" which will bring you all the results.