# External links in block not working

Tags: 7, views

I'm new to drupal 7. I am trying to configure a side menu that has links in it from a block within a View I made.

All I want to do is to make it so that the external links in that menu go the actual page themselves (WITHOUT USING A MODULE SPECIFICALLY FOR LINKS).

Is this possible? Is it simply a matter of settings for the fields specific for the links. Here is a screenshot of my view from my daskboard, any help is appreciated

[image]

Comment: The view has nothing to output, you've set Content style instead of Fields. If the fields are on the node, you also need a contextual filter for the node id so the View knows what to load.

Comment: Can you give me and example of what you are talking about, which contextual filter should I use? `Content: Website (field_website_link:attributes)` ?? `Content: Link to Full News Article (field_website_url:url)`??

Comment: The contextual filter only needs to be the node id (content id). The argument should be fetched from the URL.

Comment: But when I do that it removes the links and that entire sidebar completely off the page. There is a second page that gives me options and I am honestly not sure what to pick

You mean select this one `Content: Nid` ?? 
Then what? I have two sub-sections that require input

Section 1 `When the filter value is NOT available`

Then Section 2
`When the filter value IS available or a default is provided`

After spending hours playing around I have no idea which to put for each. Any ideas?


What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Provide default value, Content ID from url.

Comment: I've done that, that simply removes the entire block from view. Regardless if it's `unformatted list` or `content` as the format field. 

Still not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Drupal 7? Try providing PHP code: `<?php return arg(1); ?>` as the default value... I forget if this is due to it being a block in D7 or not.

Comment: See: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/7164/57

Comment: Actually, hang on, this is a little confusing. You just want to show the _ONE_ node that is "Special Emphasis - Further Reading" on any page using this block? Then you don't need a contextual filter. You just need to add the fields to the view output by changing Show: Content to Show: Fields, and adding the link field. If you choose to stay with "Show: Content", then you can theme the field ouput via the View Mode selected (Teaser, or otherwise).

Comment: @Kevin

I really appreciate your help and consistency. But you are completely loosing me. I am not clear on what you mean. Break you are saying under section specific topics as I would see in the dashboard. Use my screen shots as reference please. I got another co-worker who fixed it, but the links styling looks horrible! They are just blue links and stack horribly. Any help is appreciated.